# How to execute Selenium + Junit Tests on Chrome

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, junit

I have downloaded the Chrome Driver and i am able to execute my tests on Chrome. However Only local connections are allowed for it.

How can i execute it globally on any machine without changing anything?

Comment: Have you read https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Maybe its your firewall. Can you describe your setup / network. What are you trying to achieve? Running a test from your development machine to a remote test desktop?

Comment: Currently i am running my tests on my local machine with Google Chrome.  They are running fine. If i have to run my tests on any other machine i do have to install Chrome Driver there and give the path to the driver in my tests and PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run Webdriver commands on a remote machine, Selenium Server must be installed on that machine. What I usually do to enable IE and Chrome support is place the IE and Chrome drivers right alongside Selenium Server. I can then create a batch script with the complete command, something like:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -timeout=20 -browserTimeout=60 -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\selenium\IEDriverServer_32.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\selenium\Chromedriver.exe`

That starts the server with the extra drivers and some custom settings. That way it's easy to start Selenium properly, either on startup or on demand depending on my use case for that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Create one folder Util in your test project and place the chrome drive in that.
in your driver and set the system property with the relative path. Now wher ever you take your code your chrome driver will also get copied and driver setup will always read the system property from the relative path. This way it can be run  from any machine.